# Побитовое сравнение

Tags: c#, битовые-операции

Объясните пожалуйста на пальцах. У меня есть маска в двоичном представлении `0000 0100`, я хочу во время когда пользователь вводит число, например : 4 что в двоичном равно маске, получать `true`, во всех остальных случаях `false`. Делаю вот так :

```
public static bool isTrue(byte num)
{
    byte result = (byte)(num & MASK_DAY); //Константа = 0x04;

    if(result == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

В этом случае я получаю всегда `true` когда бит другого числа, 2 разряда, равен 1, а как мне сделать что бы я получал `true` только тогда когда 2-е разряды обоих чисел совпадают, а все остальное равно 0? Или я не правильно понимаю работу с битами?

Comment: Банально `num == MASK_DAY`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Битовые маски применяются для того, чтобы проверить в числе только **интересующие** нас биты. А на остальные не обращать внимания.

Например:

- проверка, что в числе установлены те биты, которые установлены в `MASK_DAY`. Значение остальных бит нас не интересует

  ```
  if (num & MASK_DAY == MASK_DAY)
  ```
- в числе **не установлены** те биты, которые установлены в `MASK_DAY`

  ```
  if (num & MASK_DAY == 0)
  ```
- проверка, что все не установленные биты `MASK_DAY` сброшены и в `num`

  ```
  if (num | MASK_DAY == MASK_DAY)
  ```
- проверка, что все установленные биты `MASK_DAY` установлены и в `num`, а не установленные - сброшены

  ```
  if (num == MASK_DAY)
  ```

Comment: Подскажите == это побитовый оператор? Правильно так сравнивать?

Comment: @Winteriscoming Это обычный оператор сравнения, который проверяет равенство двух операндов. А два числа равны между собой тогда и только тогда, когда равны между собой каждая пара бит

Comment: Подскажите пжл, зачем тогда делать & и == использовать в одном выражении?

Comment: @Winteriscoming мы сначала применяем побитовое "И". Соответственно, в значении 1 останутся только те биты, которые установлены в 1 и в маске, и в числе. Если после этого результат совпадает с маской - значит все биты, которые установлены в 1 в маске установлены в 1 и в числе. Но при этом число может не совпадать с маской. Пример: `1010 & 0010 ==0010` - `true`. Но `1010 ==0010`- `false`

Answer (score 3):

Повторять уже [написанное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/742508/198316) не буду, но некоторые уточнения внесу.

**1. Битовые (поразрядные) операции в качестве результата возвращают число.**

это означает, что если вы, например, выполнили операцию

```
byte res = 0x04 & 0x0f

00000100 //0x04 
&&&&&&&&  
00001111 //0x0f
========  
00000100 //0x04
```

то переменная res будет содержать 0x04

**2. В C# в условном операторе `if` допустимы только логические выражения**

Это означает, что мы не можем использовать результат поразрядной операции (число) в качестве условия для `if`, поэтому нам необходимо использовать логическую (результат типа bool [true/false]) операцию сравнения `==` для проверки, что после применения поразрядной операции получилось нужное число.

---

В большинстве случаев достаточно простых логических операций сравнения. Битовые операции имеет смысл использовать тогда, и только тогда, когда вас интересует состояние конкретных бит в числе, например в случае упаковки нескольких логических переменных в одно число с целью экстремальной экономии памяти.

Comment: Почему получается что `res` получает `0x04` а не второе, из за того что оно больше, или подошло по биту? Если бы там было `00001000` то вернуло бы 0x0f потому что не совпал ни 1 бит?

Comment: @Winteriscoming потому что поразрядная операция применяется к каждой паре бит независимо. Я специально вставил фрагмент с битовыми представлениями аргументов и результата и между каждой парой бит вставлена операция. Битовые операции - это не проверки, а именно операции с битами. Алгебру логики, я полагаю, вы помните.